# Possible to capture all events in a web browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, project

I am working on a pet project and am at the research stage.

### Quick summary

I am trying to intercept all form submits, onclick, and every single keydown.  My library of choice is either jquery, or jquery + prototypejs.  I figure I can batch up the events into a queue/stack and send it back to the server in time interval batches to keep performance relatively stable.

#### Concerns

Form submits and change's would be relatively simple.. Something like

```
$("form :inputs").bind("change", function() { ... record event... });
```

But how to ensure I get precedence over the applications handlers as I have a habit of putting return false on a lot of my form handlers when there is a validation issue.  As I understand it, that effectively stops the event in its tracks.

### My project

For my smaller remote clients I will put their products onto a VPS or run it in my home data center.  Currently I use a basic authentication system, given a username/password they see the website and then hopefully send me somewhat sane notes on what is broken or should be tweaked.

As a better solution, I've written a simple proxy web server that does the above but allows me to have one DNS entry and then depending on credentials it makes an internal request relaying headers and re-writing URLS as needed.  Every single html/text or application/* request is compressed and shoved into a sqlite table so I can partially replay what they've done.  Now I am shifting to the frontend and would like to capture clicks, keydown's, and submits on everything on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get past the `return false;` issue, try working with custom events.

```
// Bind custom event to all forms

    $('form').bind('custom_submit_event',function() {
        alert('custom submit event');
    });

// Bind submit event to all forms that triggers the custom event

    $('form').submit(function() {
        $(this).trigger('custom_submit_event');
    });

// Your regular submit event for a specific form

    $('#myform').submit(function() {
        // Run validation/submission code
        return false;
    });
```

I haven't used custom events very often, but this works for me. Don't know why it wouldn't work with other events as well.

You could also assign handlers to the `document`. As long as you don't hit the `return false;` issue, they events will bubble up to the document. Might be better (more efficient) than having the overhead of many event handlers throughout the page.

```
    $(document).click(function() {
        alert('click')
    })
    .keydown(function() {
        alert('keydown')
    });
```

Comment: I think your idea will probably be the best working solution, going to write up a quick mockup today and regardless of result post it to my misc. google project dump.